# Language construct ~to by

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, prepositional-passive

What is the difference between the following two wrt their meaning for **to by** versus **by**:

> An *Internet standard* is thoroughly a tested specification that is
>   useful to and adhered **to by** those who work with the internet.

What if the group of words **adhered to by those** in the above sentence is replaced with **adhered by those**?
If doing this would bring any change in overall meaning of the sentence?

Comment: It's not "to by"... it's "adhered to" followed by "by".

Comment: Some other issues: "An Internet standard is *a thoroughly* tested specification that *is* useful to..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alternate construction wouldn't work.

The simplest answer to this is that *adhered to* is a verb phrase in and of itself. You cannot drop the preposition.

> - I adhere to kosher dietary restrictions.
> - I adhere kosher dietary restrictions.

The first example is grammatically correct, and while the second sentence may be understood in meaning, it's wrong.

Other verbs don't require this structure:

> - I follow kosher dietary restrictions.

*Follow* works as a verb without a prepositional component. Other verbs may require these components some or all of the time in order to be grammatically correct.

*Adhere* is almost never used without a preposition, but in the case of some of the other examples below, such as *submit*, certain usages do not require a preposition.

> - I adhere to...
> - I aspire to...
> - I abstain from...
> - I refrain from...
> - I comply with...
> - I interact with...
> - I conform with...
> - I defer to...
> - I submit to...

Going even further, you can link these verb phrases with other constructions:

> - I aspire to adhere to kosher dietary restrictions.
> - I aspire to follow kosher dietary restrictions.

As is the case with many languages, you'll have to rely on memory to determine which verbs require special constructions in order to make grammatical sense.